# How to add/subtract dates on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

On button click, I am trying to add/subtract the given date.
 Making use of `setDate` and `getTime` I managed to get the correct date.

```
const subtract = (params) => {
    const subtracted = new Date(
      params.setTime(new Date(params).getTime() - (3600 / 60) * 60000)
    ).toLocaleTimeString("en-UK", options);
    console.log("subtracted", subtracted);
    return subtracted;
  };
```

If you check in the `dev tools/console` the value called `subtracted` you will see that subtraction works correct. But on the table it is still the old value, it doesn't update. 
Here is the code and the [sandbox demo link][1]

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/aggridsubtract-time-vqh95f
```

```
import React from "react";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";

const options = {
  hour: "2-digit",
  minute: "2-digit",
  hour12: false
};
function App() {
  const [gridApi, setGridApi] = React.useState(null);
  const [gridColumnApi, setGridColumnApi] = React.useState(null);

  const onGridReady = (params) => {
    setGridApi(params.api);
    setGridColumnApi(params.columnApi);
  };

  const subtract = (params) => {
    const subtracted = new Date(
      params.setTime(new Date(params).getTime() - (3600 / 60) * 60000)
    ).toLocaleTimeString("en-UK", options);
    console.log("subtracted", subtracted);
    return subtracted;
  };

  var rowData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "John",
      time: new Date()
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "David",
      time: new Date()
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Dan",
      time: new Date()
    }
  ];

  const defaultColDef = {
    flex: 1,
    editable: true
  };

  const columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: "Name",
      field: "name"
    },
    {
      headerName: "time",
      field: "time",
      cellRenderer: ({ value }) => (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => subtract(value)}>-</button>
          {value.toLocaleTimeString("en-UK", options)}
          <button>+</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 align="center">React-App</h1>
      <div>
        <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: "700px" }}>
          <AgGridReact
            columnDefs={columnDefs}
            rowData={rowData}
            defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
            onGridReady={onGridReady}
          ></AgGridReact>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+subtract+dates+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Hey @mplungjan , thanks for your notice. I tried to improve my question. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: You need to manage separate states for each object inside `rowData` to update dates. Better to have a child component to manage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a child component to manage `date` state of each object in `rowData` array. I have updated your code. Use it as an example to improve your code. (please refer the link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/aggridsubtract-time-forked-5qbsju))